# Is it possible to change the maximum range on the Android proximity sensor?

Tags: android, android-sensors, proximitysensor

Can I use the proximity sensor to detect something further than the maximum range returned by sensor.getMaximumRange()? Something like 50cm instead of the 8cm I'm getting now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. Usually the proximity sensor give back [0 or max range](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) because this is usually used to turn the screen off when you call and your head is near the phone.

> Note: Some proximity sensors only support a binary near or far
>   measurement. In this case, the sensor should report its maximum range
>   value in the far state and a lesser value in the near state.

After it really depends of the hardware of the phone but I doubt that you can outranged the maxRange value. You can still take a look on [aosp about the sensor stack](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-stack.html) but the native fragment is close to what [android.hardware](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/package-summary.html) is.